# How to systematically find roots of $x^2-x-132 = 0$ with Po-Shen Loh's method?

Tags: quadratics

Po-Shen Loh  in his famous [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBalWWHYFQc) shows how to systematically find quadratic equation's roots.

He find the roots for following quadratic equation.

$x^2-8x+12 = 0$

> **Product**: 12,   **Sum**: 8

He divides **sum** by **half** i.e. **8/2 = 4**

Proceeds to find roots: $4 - u$ & $4 + u.$

$ (4 - u) * (4 + u) = 12$

$16 - u^2 = 12  $

$16 - 12 = u^2$

$ 4 = u^2$

$u = \pm2$

Now, if we substitute value of $u$ in $4 - u$ & $4 + u$, we get, $2$ and $6$

But, this methods doesn't yield result for $x^2-x-132 = 0$

Let's divide **sum** by **half** i.e. $(1) * 1/2 = 1/2$

Proceeds to find roots: $1/2-u$ & $1/2+ u$

$ (1/2 - u) * (1/2 + u) = - 132$

$1/4 - u^2 = - 132  $

$1/4 + 132 = u^2$

$ 529/4 = u^2$

$ 132.25 = u^2$

$u = ?$

> How to systematically find roots of $x^2-x-132 = 0$ with above method?

Comment: You messed up because you put $\dots = 132$ while it should be $-132$.

Comment: Seems to me your hangup is... the square root of 132.25 isnt obvious to you.  Not that the method is any more difficult.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Yeah! I gave up seeing decimal :( But it is sure shot way to find roots with any guessing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u^2=132.25$$

$$u=\pm11.5$$

$$\frac{1}{2}+11.5=12$$

$$\frac{1}{2}-11.5=-11$$

$$(x-12)(x+11)=0$$

The $-132$ does change things, by the way.

Comment: I gave up seeing decimal :/

Comment: @Ubihatt That's fine, but just remember that we're all trying to help you.

Comment: @Kman3 and get rep ;-)